# Роль частицы "уж" в вопросительных предложениях?

Tags: частицы

Какую роль частица "уж" выполняет в предложениях:

1. Уж не ты ли взял мою тетрадь?
2. Уж не выпить ли нам чаю?

Во всех словарях указано, что в вопросительных предложениях частица "уж" усиливает вопрос. Но подобное объяснение не раскрывает сути. А как вы понимаете, для чего здесь используется "уж"?

Answer (score 3):

Уж - усилительная частица, по-моему, здесь она тоже усиливает местоимение ТЫ.

*Это ты взял мою тетрадь?* - вопрос звучит резко.

*Не ты ли взял мою тетрадь?* - вопрос смягчился.

*Уж не ты ли взял мою тетрадь?* - появилась экспрессия, почти гнев, обращённый к собеседнику, почти обвинение.

*Не выпить ли нам чаю?* - нейтральное приглашение.

*Уж не выпить ли нам чаю?* - экспрессивное приглашение, частица усиливает значимость действия: всё, хватит, в самом деле, пора пить чай, это будет полезнее.

Усилительная частица УЖ иногда употребляется в начале предложений в значении „действительно”, „в самом деле”, „право же”, например:  Уж мы пойдём ломить стеною, уж постоим мы головою за родину свою (Лермонтов); Уж не тётка ли твоя тебе это натолковала? (Тургенев); Уж не прогневайтесь, что потревожила вас (Гончаров).

https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/chastitsyi-137304.html

Answer (score 2):

> Есть еще один тип высказываний, как будто похожих на общие вопросы, но допускающих частицу уж. Это высказывания вида: *Уж не P ли?*.  Ср. *Уж не влюбилась ли наша Маша в Иван Иваныча? Уж не пародия ли он?* (А.С.Пушкин). Но  подобные высказывания  лишь внешне напоминают общие вопросы. Как и примеры непосредственно выше, они содержат следующую пресуппозицию: ‘ожидалось, что P не имеет место’, а кроме того выражают удивление говорящего по поводу того, что P имеет место.

Урысон Е.В. "*УЖЕ* И *УЖ*: ВАРИАТИВНОСТЬ, ПОЛИСЕМИЯ, ОМОНИМИЯ?" / Компьютерная лингвистика и интеллектуальные технологии: Труды международной конференции «Диалог 2007».

"Примеры непосредственно выше" показывают использование частицы в риторических вопросах. До этого автор показывает, что `уж`, в отличие от `уже`, не употребляется в общих вопросах и ответах на них.

Полный текст с ещё более детальным анализом значений `уж` и `уже` можно найти в открытом доступе на сайте конференции.

Comment: [Оставлю ссылку](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2007/materials/html/81.htm) в комментарии. Это интересно, спасибо.

Comment: И ещё [эту](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2008/materials/html/47.htm) заодно.

Answer (score 2):

Частица УЖ имеет **усилительное значение?** Но ведь многие частицы называют усилительными. Как считает автор вопроса, **"подобное объяснение не раскрывает сути"**, и я с ним согласна.

Попробуем обратиться к словарям.

1. **Временное значение слов УЖ, УЖЕ является основным**

Уже  – **временное наречие**, отнесенное обычно к глаголу. Оно говорит о том, что к данному моменту произошло действие или изменилось состояние: *Он уже пришел. Солнце уже стояло высоко.*

Может относиться к прилагательным и наречиям, определяя **изменение признака** или обстоятельства по времени: печь уже теплая; он смотрел уже дружелюбно; они встретились уже дома. Но **временное значение** присутствует в этом наречии всегда.

А в частице УЖЕ? Значение примерно то же самое: *уже который день идет дождь, уже пятый раз тебе говорю.*  **Частица перемещается к слову**, да только мало что меняется – **нового качества нет.**

2. **Когда появляется новое качество**

Слово УЖ – укороченное УЖЕ, и сначала  в словарной статье ничего нового не видно, но вот наконец появляются **более интересные значения**:

**В начале предложения:**

Усиливает просьбу, утверждение. *Уж вы скажите, пожалуйста. Уж вы не забудьте меня. Уж я тебя не покину.*

Усиливает вопросительный характер предложения (обычно с отрицанием). *Уж не рассердился ли ты? Уж не задумал ли ты что-нибудь?*

Теперь это детерминант, который относится ко всему предложению, то есть   существует самостоятельно, да и **значение времени вроде бы не доминирует**, как раньше, а отодвигается на второй план.

3. **Этимология слова УЖЕ =  У + ЖЕ**

Что ж, самое время обратиться **к этимологии**. Наречие  УЖЕ сложное,  в др.-рус. языке с 11 века, ст.-сл. вариант ***юже***, ЖЕ – усилительная частица , а У – это временное наречие «теперь, тогда».

4. **УЖ может обозначать  изменение отношения**

Похоже, что  значение частицы УЖ может обозначать **изменение отношения к ситуации** после размышления или получения  какой-либо информации, В этом случае прояляется значение "теперь, тогда", например:

*Теперь, после того, как я вам всё рассказал, вы уж не забудьте меня.*

*Тогда  я могу предположить, что ты рассержен. Уж не рассердился ли ты?*

5. **Решение задачи**

***Уж не ты ли взял мою тетрадь?***

Тетрадь пропала!  Только что лежала на столе, а теперь ее нет. А там конспекты лекций, скоро экзамен. Куда она могла деться? Мистика какая-то! Однокурсник помогает ее искать, причем  очень старается – видно,  переживает за меня. С чего бы это? А ведь у него нет такого конспекта. И вполне  логический вывод: ***Уж  не он ли взял мою тетрадь?***

***Уж не выпить ли нам чаю?*** Здесь тоже, вероятно, имела место какая-то **ситуация**, которая и привела к такому решению. Например, выяснили отношения, помирились, тогда уж  и чаю можно выпить. Или: Если нет других вариантов, то не выпить ли тогда чаю.

И делаем вывод. Частица УЖ в приведенных примерах, которую  называют усилительной, не утрачивает своего **временного значения**. Только обозначает она здесь **не изменение** признака во времени, как обычно, а **изменение отношения к ситуации, вызванное какими-либо причинами.**

Если соотнести этот вывод **с одним из ответов** (ожидалось, что P не имеет место... удивление говорящего по поводу того, что P имеет место), то есть **что-то похожее:** я никак не думал, что друг возьмет мою тетрадь, но теперь не исключаю этого.

Comment: Интересный ход мысли, Sharon. Но по моему, само по себе предложение "Не он ли взял мою тетрадь?" содержит логический вывод (предположение), а частица "уж" придает некую категоричность. Прошу еще дать пояснения.

Comment: Здесь дело не в самом  мнении (логическом предположении), а в его ИЗМЕНЕНИИ  по отношению к  оценке ситуации, именно поэтому здесь присутствует ВРЕМЕННОЕ  наречие-частица УЖ.. Получается так:  Я уже (теперь) стал думать, не он ли взял мою тетерадь?  Сначала это мне и в голову не приходило.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю: *раз некоторые другие варианты не годятся, не подойдёт ли этот? Возможно, есть ещё другие, но какие-то уже точно отсекли.*